# Instant App Fails when verifying

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

whenever I click the link and verify button in complete the association part, it gives :

- Adding asset statements failed
- Failed to link strings to AndroidManifest file
- Failed to add autoVerify to intent-filter elements
- Success!...

Why these 3 of them failed? And is it an obstacle for uploading apk
to play store? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the intent-filter statements that were added to your manifest? You may need to just add them manually rather than using the App Links wizard.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, the assetlinks.json is successfully uploaded and verified but those 3 failed messages occured, have you got the solution

Comment: I have added the expected assertlinks.json file to my website and it also has https protocol still its not working. Can anybody help.

Comment: Is this still reproducible with the latest AS Canary 8? Also, are you behind some kind of firewall?

Comment: @senaaltun, i hope your problems has been solved. can you get back if still you have problems.