# Android Instant App - Complete the Association does not verified

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Even if I uploaded the `assetlinks.json` file to my server, I give this error and can not upload my feature APK to Play Store :

[image]

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you post the `intent-filter` statements that were added to your manifest? You may need to just add them manually rather than using the App Links wizard.

Comment: It looks like you've correctly verified your domain (the last green checkmark in your screenshot). Do you see any more detailed errors in the Android Studio console that could help debug this? Also, it would probably help if you can post at least the app link portions of your manifest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instant App Fails when verifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546911/instant-app-fails-when-verifying)

Comment: </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"
          android:order = "1"
          >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:scheme="http"
            android:path="/example/*"/>
      </intent-filter> @AdamK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is as soon as you change your application module to a feature module with baseFeature true it is treated as a library. That's why you are getting the top 3 errors.

Just made the feature module application module again and you will start seeing 4 correct checks instead of 1.

As far as I know, the solution to this problem is that you should add links manually in the intent-filter, don't use the Apps Links Assistant. I did the same and was able to upload my instant app on play store.